# Unknown discriminator value C# Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am able to save my class to mongo but I am getting an error deserializing it.

I am getting an error:

> 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : Unknown discriminator value 'ProductPropertyDefinition'.'

I need help.  How to tell mongo to deserialize this correctly?

```
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ProductPropertyDefinitionCollection ProductProperties { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPropertyDefinitionCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public ProductPropertyDefinition this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (ProductPropertyDefinition)List[index];
        }
        set
        {
            List[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public ProductPropertyDefinition this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetByName(name);
        }
    }

    public int Add(ProductPropertyDefinition value)
    {
        return List.Add(value);
    }

    public void Remove(ProductPropertyDefinition value)
    {
        List.Remove(value);
    }

    public bool Contains(ProductPropertyDefinition value)
    {
        return List.Contains(value);
    }

    private ProductPropertyDefinition GetByName(string propertyName)
    {
        ProductPropertyDefinition profileItem = null;

        foreach (ProductPropertyDefinition profileProperty in InnerList)
        {
            if (profileProperty.PropertyName == propertyName)
            {
                profileItem = profileProperty;
            }
        }
        return profileItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Got it. I just needed to add a classmap:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProductPropertyDefinition>();
```